# Rewrite rule for subfolder

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have the file structure

```
index.php
.htaccess
news/index.php
news/.htaccess
```

First .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/news/
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
```

Second (news/.htaccess)

```
 RewriteEngine On
 RewriteRule . /index.php
```

Request http://test.t/news/news/61 the handles first index.php but I need to do it the second

I tried a few more options for the first .htaccess, but it did not succeed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check your Apache config file (httpd.conf) and make sure the directory you are using for your site includes the AllowOverride option.

Example:

```
<Directory "/Applications/MAMP/htdocs">
    Options All
    AllowOverride All
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>
```

Comment: Is the `http://test/news/news/61` using the wrong index.php? what does "did not succeed" mean?

Comment: yes, second receives a request, only `http://test/news/` without params ( **news/61** ). Any other requests received first.

Comment: It sounds like it's doing exactly what you told it to do. Your combined .htaccess says for the url test/news/news/61, it should open /index.php and pass no params. If you want it to use /news/index.php, then you should edit your second .htaccess to say `RewriteRule . index.php` NOT `/index.php`. Do you need the url parts in your parameters?

Comment: if you need the article number as a param, use something like: `RewriteRule news/([0-9]+) index.php?articleId=$1` that uses a regex to match `news/###` and appends the article number to the url. See http://httpd.apache.org/docs/trunk/rewrite/remapping.html

Comment: Parsing of the parameters involved in Yii, it was necessary to send them to him. Thanks!