# Wordpress/htaccess - allow access to subdirectory

Tags: wordpress, apache, .htaccess, directory, subdirectory

I have a subdirectory (`app`) I want to access that is in the root folder of my `wordpress` site. I have looked here:

https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/20152/cannot-access-non-wordpress-subdirectories-as-wordpress-overrides-them-with-a-40

I have tried the solutions and nothing worked.

I also tried adding a separate `.htaccess` file to the `app` subdirectory that looks like this:

```
DirectoryIndex index.php index.html index.htm
Options +Indexes
```

But it didn't seem to help:

The main `.htaccess` I am trying with now looks like this:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/app/(.*)$ [OR]
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [L]
</IfModule>

# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]

</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

I get a `404` error.

What am I doing wrong? If I am viewing the site on an iPhone, is clearing the safari history on the phone enough to refresh the data so it recognizes the new .htaccess? Thanks.

**UPDATE**

I added:

```
<Directory "/home/eamondev/public_html/subconscious/">
    Options All
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

to a .conf file that gets `Include`ed in `httpd.conf`, restarted apache, but didn't help.

I also tried:

```
<Directory "/home/eamondev/public_html/subconscious/">
    AllowOverride All
</Directory>
```

and it didn't work, I'm not sure if I only need `AllowOverride All` - either way this doesn't seem to help.

**UPDATE**

In a .conf file that is `Include`d in `httpd.conf`, I tried:

```
<VirtualHost 162.241.180.99:80>
    ServerName eamondev.com
    DocumentRoot /home/eamondev/public_html

    <Directory "/home/eamondev/public_html/">
      AllowOverride All
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

but it didn't help.

Is there any reason I shouldn't just make another subdomain on my server and host the files out of there so reaching them doesn't conflict with my wordpress site?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out, my domain hadn't propagated yet, so it wasn't possible to see/test any of the changes I was making. Before I realized that it was still propagating, I also thought to just create another subdomain and host the files I needed to from there.

Answer (score 0):

Use below code i think it will work.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On

# Map http://www.example.com to /app.
RewriteRule ^$ /app/ [L]

# Map http://www.example.com/x to /app/x unless there is a x in the web root.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/app/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /app/$1

# Add trailing slash to directories within app
# This does not expose the internal URL.
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^app/(.*[^/])$ http://www.example.com/$1/ [R=301]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: thanks, one question...does this just replace the `IfModule` at the top or both?

Comment: and what is `jekyll?` do you understand that all i need to do is to be able to access `index.html` in the `app` subdirectory of my wordpress root, without it redirecting me to a 404 error?

Comment: i made the changes and cleared the cache in my browser and went to http://subconscious.eamondev.com/app/index.html but it still gives 404

Comment: what about `AllowOverride All`? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13672998/rewrite-rule-for-subfolder?rq=1

Comment: also this line...`RewriteRule ^jekyll/(.*[^/])$ http://www.example.com/$1/ [R=301]` do i need to change `example.com` url to `https://subconscious.eamondev.com/$1/`?

Comment: yes change `jekyll` to `app` and `example.com` will be your site url

Comment: i changed it still no luck, im going to update with what i have so u can see..do i need the .htaccess in the subdirectory too? the file containing `DirectoryIndex....`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/180881/discussion-between-raju-eww-and-ewizard).

Comment: I am having  similar problem. do you find any solution

Comment: Not working for me either getting 'Forbidden'